# What's the most difficult multidimensional integral that Mathematica has solved?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I am interested in benchmarking numerical integration methods and am trying to develop a wider set of difficult multivariate examples. For my particular methods, I only want to look at non-negative-valued integrands, $f(x)\geq 0$, so that $\int f(x)dx\geq 0$.

To be a good benchmark, the integrand would need to be (a) multivariate, with control over the number of dimensions, $D$, (b) have an analytic result (in any $D$), (c) probably not have singularities (d) be finite and non-zero (e) be real-valued and (f) be nasty: i.e. difficult for numerical integrators to handle. Note that: the integral could be either indefinite or definite; I don't care, as long as the result is analytic.

Basically, I wanted to ask what's the nastiest multivariate integral that you have got Mathematica to determine an analytic result for?

My current winner is the following:

$f(x_1,x_2,...,x_D)= \text{sin}(x_1+x_2)^2\prod_{i=1}^{D} \text{exp}(-x_i^2) \text{sin}(10 x_i)^2$

which, in two dimensions, looks like:

```
Plot3D[Exp[-x^2] Exp[-y^2] Sin[10 x]^2  Sin[10 y]^2 Sin[x + y]^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
       PlotRange -> Full, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

By my definition, this is a fairly "nasty" function to integrate, likely to cause real pain to numerical methods.

In two dimensions, integrating between given bounds in two dimensions,

```
Integrate[Exp[-x^2] Exp[-y^2] Sin[10 x]^2  Sin[10 y]^2 Sin[x + y]^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

results in an analytic (albeit long) result:

> (1/(128 E^242))[Pi] (16 E^242 Erf[2]^2 - 
>      4 E^240 (Erf[2 + I] - I Erfi[1 + 2 I])^2 + 
>      4 E^160 (Erf[2 + I] - I Erfi[1 + 2 I]) (Erf[2 + 9 I] - 
>         I Erfi[9 + 2 I]) - E^80 (Erf[2 + 9 I] - I Erfi[9 + 2 I])^2 - 
>      16 E^142 Erf[2] (Erf[2 + 10 I] - I Erfi[10 + 2 I]) + 
>      4 E^42 (Erf[2 + 10 I] - I Erfi[10 + 2 I])^2 + 
>      4 E^120 (Erf[2 + I] - I Erfi[1 + 2 I]) (Erf[2 + 11 I] - 
>         I Erfi[11 + 2 I]) - 
>      2 E^40 (Erf[2 + 9 I] - I Erfi[9 + 2 I]) (Erf[2 + 11 I] - 
>         I Erfi[11 + 2 I]) - (Erf[2 + 11 I] - I Erfi[11 + 2 I])^2)

Because of the independent structure of the integral for dimensions 3 and above, it can easily be generalised to higher dimensions by multiplying the integral by:

```
Integrate[Exp[-x^2] Sin[10 x]^2 , {x, -2, 2}]
```

which has an analytic result.

Comment: What are you asking about?

Comment: @AlexTrounev not sure I understand your question? I am trying to find a list of difficult integrals that retain analytic solutions for reasons I mention in the question: specifically, to develop suitable benchmarks for numerical integrators. At the moment, these are heavily lacking.

Comment: Are you looking for some D-dimensional integrals to test `NIntegrate[]`?

Comment: Probably not -- the trouble is, `NIntegrate` depends on the sorts of numerical methods that we want to test. Also, the trouble with `NIntegrate` is that it's hard to imagine moving from a handful of dimensions to hundreds.

Comment: @AlexTrounev: ben18785 has or expects to have software that integrates numerically, and they want to test that software. Testing by using other numerical integrators is not easy since those other numerical integrators may share the same bugs or drawbacks. Testing simple integrals provides inadequate testing because they are not challenging for the integrators. Having integrals that are difficult to integrate numerically but that have analytic solutions can provide a good testing method because the analytic solutions can be evaluated numerically with less error than integrating numerically.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for explanation. What is a reason to discuss it on this forum without looking on software?

Comment: @AlexTrounev the purpose is that Mathematica is the foremost engine for symbolic integration -- I can't think of a better place for this post. Also, I thought MMA users might find it fun!

Comment: @ben18785 What kind of answer you supposed to get?